# Did MSCA supersede MCA or do both still fund new projects?

Tags: funding, eu

According to the page [About the Marie Skłodowska-Curie Actions](http://ec.europa.eu/research/mariecurieactions/about-msca/actions/index_en.htm):

> As of January 2014, with the move to Horizon 2020, the Marie Curie Actions are now called the Marie Skłodowska-Curie actions (MSCA). This change better reflects the Polish roots of this extraordinary scientist who inspired and inspires the programme.

This seems to suggest that Marie Curie Actions no longer issue new funding calls.  However, also on the website of the European Commission is [About the Marie Curie Actions](http://ec.europa.eu/research/mariecurieactions/about-mca/actions/index_en.htm), which makes no mention of this action being finished/superseded.

Do both the Marie Skłodowska-Curie Actions and the Marie Curie Actions exist concurrently and do both still issue funding calls, or has MSCE simply been superseded by MCA and is the MCA page out of date¹?

---

¹<sup>When accessed 2015-04-04, the MCA page states it is last updated 2015-03-12.</sup>

Comment: I don't know the background here, but it really sounds like they just changed the name of the program, without changing how the program actually works. Presumably the EC site just never got updated to refer to the new name.

Comment: @NateEldredge The contents seem different though.  It seems simplified.

Answer (score 1):

The MCA page is indeed out of date. 
See e.g. http://ec.europa.eu/research/mariecurieactions/about-mca/actions/iif/index_en.htm
where if you click on "How do we apply", there is a link to "People Work Programme 2013".

The name MCA was changed to MSCA with the end of the 7th Framework Programme ([FP7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framework_Programmes_for_Research_and_Technological_Development#FP6_and_FP7)), and the start of [Horizon 2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framework_Programmes_for_Research_and_Technological_Development#Horizon_2020).

Comment: Interestingly, even those out of date open calls linked from the MCA page are MSCA, not MCA...